# Android reverse geocoding call fails

Tags: android, kotlin, geocoding, google-play-console, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on an app with multiple Google APIs. The app has a **Marker** which can be moved with drag&drop or click on map. I have a listener that takes the new **LatLng** and makes a call to this endpoint - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=LAT_LNG&key=API_KEY

The Retrofit method looks like this, the base URL is already added in the Retrofit.Builder() and here I add the **geocode/json** part

```
@GET(ApiRoute.GEOCODE)
    suspend fun getAddress(
        @Path("latlng") latLng: String?,
        @Path("key") apiKey: String,
        ): Response<ReverseGeocodeEntity>
```

Environment:

- I have the **INTERNET** permission
- I have an **API key** (which I use above for the "key") defined in Google Play Console which is restricted on **Android apps** where I have 5 **SHA1 keys** added (2 local debug for developers, 1 Firebase, 1 Google Play Store for production and 1 Keystore certificate)
- 7 **APIs** in the above **API key** where the **Maps SDK for Android** and **Geocoding API** are present.

My call fails with **status: REQUEST_DENIED** and **error_message: This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address IP_ADDRESS, with empty referer**. Weirdly, it works if I take out the **Android apps** restriction..

Everything I looked up is either old or not relevant.. and the setup looks good from my point of view, I don't think I've missed anything.. did someone encounter this issue?

Comment: Google has map and geocoding APIs for ANdroid that do all this work for you.  Any reason you're not using those instead of making the network call yourself?

Comment: I've seen somewhere complaints that it's not as accurate, it was an older article here on StackOverflow, probably it got better since then but other than that I didn't give it a shot.. I can aswell try but in my honest opinion, I thought that's the way to work, with the endpoints

Comment: It uses the same APIs under the hood.  The SDK is just as accurate.  Maybe you were confusing the Android LocationManager vs Google's FusedLocationProvider, which are different than the geocoding APIs (and which is more accurate can be summed up as "it depends")

Comment: Yeah, you we're right, I could do the job with the Geocoder object.. and get the address from there, much better.

Thanks a lot!